# Cómo obtengo el nombre de un JRadioButton seleccionado en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo 2 JRadioButton y un ButtonGroup, declarados globalmente en mi programa en Java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private JRadioButton rdbtnHombre;
private JRadioButton rdbtnMujer;
private ButtonGroup grupoSexo;
```

luego, dentro de mi frame tengo:

```
grupoSexo = new ButtonGroup();
grupoSexo.add(rdbtnHombre);
grupoSexo.add(rdbtnMujer);
```

entonces, para saber qué ha seleccionado el usuario, probé con esto pero, no me funciona, String se queda en `null`:

```
String sexoSelected = grupoSexo.getSelection().getActionCommand();
dato_invitado.setSexo(sexoSelected);
```

Quiero pasarle el String "Hombre" o "Mujer" al constructor.

Alguna idea?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no te devuelva `null` primero tienes que setear el ActionCommand para cada botón. Ejemplo para Hombre:

```
rdbtnHombre.setActionCommand("Hombre");
```

Comment: vale gracias, déjame probar. No sabía ese dato.

Answer (score 0):

```
rdbtnHombre=neq JRadioButton("Hombre");
```

Hiciste esto? Quizá por eso te marca null por qué el objeto está declarado pero no inicializado.

Comment: si, había hecho eso, al parecer hay que hacer primero: rdbtnHombre.setActionCommand("Hombre");, antes de obtener el texto.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez hay formas mas cortas de escribir lo que yo hice, pero me funciono. ya que mi idea era guardar el valor que se había seleccionado. creando un String

```
    String gener = "";
    gener = buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();

    if (jRadioButton_male.isSelected()) {
        gener = "Male";
    } else if (jRadioButton_female.isSelected()) {
        gener = "Female";      
    } else if (jRadioButton_custom.isSelected()) {
        gener = "Custom";
    }
```